# MatPlotLib no muestra el gráfico

Tags: python, matplotlib

Mi función no muestra los gráficos que debería, soy bastante nuevo, y no sé por qué no se acumulan las imágenes a mostrar. Aquí el código:

```
#Visualizamos la perdida del modelo entrenado.
def visualizarResultados(train_loss, valid_loss):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
    plt.plot(range(1,len(train_loss)+1),train_loss, label='Training Loss')
    plt.plot(range(1,len(valid_loss)+1),valid_loss,label='Validation Loss')

    #Posicion mas baja de la perdida en la validacion
    minposs = valid_loss.index(min(valid_loss))+1
    plt.axvline(minposs, linestyle='--', color='r', label='Parada')

    plt.xlabel('Epochs')
    plt.ylabel('loss')
    plt.ylim(0, 0.5) 
    plt.xlim(0, len(train_loss)+1)
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.legend()
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
    fig.savefig('loss_plot.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

Tras esto llamo a la función y no se me acumula la imagen, solo me aparece la línea roja.

Adjunto una imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias por todo.

Comment: Hola, adjunto una imagen para que podáis ver como sale la gráfica.

Comment: Estás ajustando de forma explícita y arbitraria los limites del eje `y` mediante  `ylim`, posiblemente tus gráficas se dibujen por encima de 0.5 o por debajo de 0 (`train_loss` y `valid_loss` no tiene valores entre 0 y 0.5) en el eje y por lo que no las ves, comenta la línea `plt.ylim(0, 0.5)`  y prueba a ver que pasa.

Comment: Es cierto, ahora sí que se ajusta a los datos. Estaba fuera del rango de visualización.